# AVAssetImageGenerator generate a black picture

Tags: ios, swift

I made a mutable video composition from 2 video assets. Also I write instruction layers for them. Everything is ok, video composition is playable in AVPlayer and also is exported with success.
Then I try to generate an image from current player time, it made the image only from the first video.
If timeline passed the second video, it made a black image.

Here is my code for generating images:

```
let imageGenerator = AVAssetImageGenerator(asset: mixComposition)
imageGenerator.appliesPreferredTrackTransform = true
imageGenerator.requestedTimeToleranceAfter = .zero
imageGenerator.requestedTimeToleranceBefore = .zero
do {
   let time = (assetPlayer?.currentItem?.currentTime())!   
   let imageRef = try imageGenerator.copyCGImage(at: time, actualTime: nil)
         let image = UIImage(cgImage: imageRef)
         return image
} catch let error as NSError {
            print("\(error.description)")
}
```

Here is my AVMutableComposition tracks on debug:

```
[<AVMutableCompositionTrack: 0x2800e7d60 trackID = 1, mediaType = vide, editCount = 3>, <AVMutableCompositionTrack: 0x2801cfd00 trackID = 2, mediaType = soun, editCount = 1>, <AVMutableCompositionTrack: 0x2801cf9c0 trackID = 3, mediaType = vide, editCount = 4>, <AVMutableCompositionTrack: 0x2800f4220 trackID = 4, mediaType = soun, editCount = 2>]
```

I even try:

```
let time = assetPlayer?.currentTime()
```

without success.
Also if I change the video with order, it made the same, generate an image only from the first video in the player time range.

I really don't know that can be the problem. Did someone meet this problem?

UPDATE:
Find a solution by adding

```
imageGenerator.videoComposition = {my_videoComposition_object}
```